# Find records in subforms from main form with a combo selection and date field

Tags: ms-access

I have couple of subforms placed on main form. Mainform and subforms are linked with linkmaster ID and child ID. This enables me to place a single combobox on main form with 2 fields (my selection field+date field) which actually is bind to key ID. This combo box loads with repeated combination of both fields which is very complicated to select to find records in subforms. 
I would like to know if there is possible way to place separate combobox to select myselection and another date field to enter date so that subforms are filtered based on key ID.

Comment: Provide more details, give example to explain the problem.

Comment: I am trying to find records on subform using master link ID and child link ID. Mainform has records sets created based on textfield and date field. If i use a combobox for users to find records in subforms using ID, i have to add a combobox with this two fields as every record in subform binds to ID. I want users to be able to set texfield value and pick date from date field to find binding records in subforms.

Basically what i want is when users select textfield value and date from date field, a code to generate corresponding ID for this selection and then search subforms using this ID